# Problem with animating the states of bodies in a 2 body simulation

Tags: python, matplotlib, simulation, matplotlib-animation

As a novice coder, I set out to create a 2-body simulation using the Runge-Kutta method. My objective was to animate the motion of these bodies over time to visualize their orbits accurately. However, despite my best efforts, the code isn't functioning as intended.

The issue arises when trying to update the positions of the bodies and animate their orbits. While the initial state of the bodies is correctly displayed, the expected dynamic animation is not occurring. The bodies remain stationary, and I can't figure out why they aren't moving as they should.

To give some context, I have carefully implemented the Runge-Kutta integration method, calculating gravitational forces, and updating the positions and velocities of the bodies for each time step. I have also tried different approaches to plot the bodies and their orbits using the scatter and plot functions from matplotlib, but the problem persists.

My suspicion is that there might be an error in the integration process or an issue with setting up the animation correctly. I have consulted online resources, reviewed relevant documentation, and asked for advice from more experienced coders. Unfortunately, I have not been able to identify the root cause of the problem.

I am sharing the relevant code snippets and the steps I have taken so far:

Defining the Body class with mass, position, velocity, and an orbit array to store position updates over time.
Calculating the gravitational force between the two bodies using the gravitational constant and the distance formula.
Implementing the Runge-Kutta integration method to update the positions and velocities of the bodies for each time step (dt).
Setting up the initial conditions for both bodies, such as mass, initial positions, and velocities.
Creating a 3D plot with matplotlib and initializing the scatter plots and lines to display the bodies and their orbits.
Attempting to update the positions of the bodies and the lines for each frame of the animation.
Despite going through the code meticulously, I am unable to pinpoint the exact cause of the issue. I believe I might be missing something fundamental in the animation process or not updating the line plots correctly.```

```
def update(frame, body1, body2, line1, line2):
    range_kutta_integration(body1, body2, dt)
    range_kutta_integration(body2, body1, dt)

    body1.orbit.append(body1.position.copy())
    body2.orbit.append(body2.position.copy())

    line1.set_data_3d(*zip(*body1.orbit))
    line2.set_data_3d(*zip(*body2.orbit))

    return line1, line2

ax.plot([body1.position[0] * SCALE], [body1.position[1] * SCALE], [body1.position[2] * SCALE], 'ro', markersize=5, label='Body 1')
ax.plot([body2.position[0] * SCALE], [body2.position[1] * SCALE], [body2.position[2] * SCALE], 'bo', markersize=5, label='Body 2')

line1, = ax.plot([], [], [], c='gray', linewidth=0.5)
line2, = ax.plot([], [], [], c='gray', linewidth=0.5)

ax.set_xlim(-1.5e11 * SCALE, 1.5e11 * SCALE)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5e11 * SCALE, 1.5e11 * SCALE)
ax.set_zlim(-1.5e11 * SCALE, 1.5e11 * SCALE)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_title('2-Body Simulation in 3D')
ax.legend()

ani = ArtistAnimation(fig, [update(frame, body1, body2, line1, line2) for frame in range(100)], interval=200, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include a [mre]. We can't help you if we can't reproduce what you are experiencing. (And we can't help you neither if we had to debug your whole program, hence the "minimal" part. Reduce the problem the the very core of what is not working, and then produce a standalone example showing that)

Comment: For example, we don't have `range_kutta_integration` (I take it is a home made function, since the guy's name is Runge, not Range). And you even said yourself that you suspect the problem may lie in that function!

Comment: You have two problems at once, the integration of the EoM and the Matplotlib animation. I'd suggest you work first on the easier problem (animation) using fake data, and later focus on the EoM.

Comment: If you, e.g., change the sign of one of the initial velocities the solution will be different, won't it? and in your code you don't mention velocities... of course you could however take them into account, as what you posted is TOTALLY OPAQUE.